# How to update my profile information

Tags: support, stackexchange.com, network-profile

When I click "Update profile info" a small window appears prompting "Choose a site to copy profile information from:" and drop down list of Stack Exchange sites I am registered on. How do I update my profile information there?

Comment: @ Peter Mortensen, redhand: Gentlemen, my mistake was that instead of click "Edit Profile & Settings" I did click "Network Profile". I apologize. Many thanks for the edit and for helpful answer.

Comment: don't apologize. It's bad UX and entirely unintuitive that something called a "Network Profile" should be copied from a sub-network, and furthermore to be uneditable.

Answer (score 5):

That will happen when you're trying to update your profile info appear on [SE main site](https://stackexchange.com/users/current)

The prompt asking you from which site you want to copy your information. Like other communities, you can't enter the text details there. You have to copy one of the existing profile info. If nothing, just create the profile info on any site. Then select that site and click **copy**

[image]

Then your SE profile is updated with the details from that site.

**Remember** It won't update your profile info on any communities. It just  that you can see in the above image.

**If you want to update you profile info in communities**

go to site -> profile (the image) -> Edit profile and settings.

After edit, at the bottom, you can see 2 buttons. One is for saving changes just for that community and the next one is for changing the info to all communities.

Comment: Very roundabout way of editing a global profile accessed by clicking your avatar. Bad UX. If there is such a thing as a "Network Profile", we should simply be able to click that and hit edit.